# How can I check if contenteditable caret is inside { }

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay so i'm currently attempting to make a text editor for css, basically I need to add a tab automatically on new line if the caret is inside { }.
I have tried a few ways to go about this and have removed it all as nothing seemed to work, any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: `I have tried a few ways` -> then show it! It might be helpful to us...

Comment: Sorry, I deleted what I attempted because there were no indications of it being close to working.

Comment: well it is not easy because you need to get reference to the parent, check the index of the cursor and see if it is in it. Now if you have html markup in it, makes it even more fun. It is not an easy task.

Comment: Yeah just as I assumed, could you point me in the right direction to get the text of the previous line of the contenteditable? I'm sure i could work it out from there.

Comment: Do you want to autoformat all the content (for example after pasting), or just indenting a new line, when pressing enter?

Comment: I think autoformat sounds better so i'd prefer that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection). It has everything you need. Including detecting where the cursor is, determining the surrounding HTML elements and characters, etc.

It is meant to help with identifying selected text but is very robust.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

Comment: Thank you, i'm sure i'll be able to get it working using this.